# Is using .net Exceptions as WCF fault contracts a security risk?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, security, fault

While fiddling with WCF fault contracts, I was hoping I could reuse my custom Exception inheritance tree as TDetail in my Faults. After getting this to work, I started thinking this through (yes, after doing the work, you know that's the best time to think). And I noticed that the client gets the full stacktrace of the exceptions that are serialized as TDetail.

Now I was thinking that this is the exact reason you don't turn on `<servicedebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />`. But I'm not sure. Would it be a security risk for me to use my exceptions as TDetail? And what are my other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, it can be a security risk in that it reveals more about your internal systems to the outside world.  However, the TDetail can be anything, so you could create new exception options that keep the messages and interesting exception information youd like to keep but clears out secured data like the stack trace and then serializes just those parts you approve of to the client.

Comment: I alread tried doing this using DataContracts on my custom exceptions, but it turns out you can't mix DataContracts and ISerializable objects this way. So to implement this I should either reimplement the `ISerializable.GetObjectData` method of my custom exceptions, or implement equivalent FaultContracts. Given that I like my Intellisense (which you don't get while implementing GetObjectData), and I like the magical support of WCF tools for DataContracts I went with the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Exposing stack trace isn't so big security risc but potentialy can give atacker more information aboute you system (database, libs, etc. ). So in my opinion you should turn details of in production environment but they are a great help when debugging.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out what exactly would be the security risk.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on who are the consumers of your service. If lets say you are opening it to the outside world, it would not be a good idea to pass these details to the clients of the service, because it gives the consumers of the service an idea about things that could cause a security breach. But if you are lets say using it internally and managed well and you want them to some how be able to do some thing with these details, then its your call, cause at the end of the day its probably behind a firewall not open to the outside world and on a network being controlled by an administrator Im guessing.

Comment: I don't trust my internal users ;-) (yes I'm paranoid). Seriously though; when a company reaches a certain number of employees, I stop viewing my users as "internal", I don't know them all...

Comment: Yes but you obviously did not understand what I said. If they are internal they would some how be behind a fire-wall, the systems would be monitored, the users would be known, and like I did also say do you want to handle the responses you provide to the en-users on their end some how, since they are internal you probably would be programming the client-side of things too. It would be a managed and well-controlled environment, thats IF you want to do any thing on the client-side of things, based on your FaultExceptions.